# Angular: HttpClient error with empty 200/201 response (always calls JSON.parse(""))

Tags: json, angular

While using Angular `HttpClient` `post`, it seems the default is to treat the response as JSON string. This caused error even for 201 response when the response body is empty as empty string `""` fails `JSON.parse()`.

The solution is to specify `responseType: "text"` as additional option, so that empty body is not treated as error.

However, the API endpoint does return error description in JSON **when** the request fails (i.e. empty on success, JSON on error).

How do you construct the `HttpClient` `post` so that I can get the error message object back when it fails and success does not count as error?

e.g.:

```
.subscribe(() => {
    // do something for success, no return object as the body is empty
  , error => {
    // do something with the returned error object
    // right now success is still counted as an error due to the issue above
  }
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the API use 204 for empty response, instead of 200?

Comment: @RaulSauco Updated for you. Cheers.

Comment: I think angular is using the response codes to guess the type of the response, if there is a problem, it does not expect `201` or `200` but some other code, like `422` for validation errors or `500` for server error. For an empty response, but no error, it should be `204`. Could you try with that? I have a few angular apps that send requests to a few different APIs and I never saw this problem before.

Comment: @RaulSauco yes 204 works. I guess it happens when you are dealing with some API endpoints that return 200, 201 with empty body instead of `{}`. But is there a way to workaround them on the client side as I cannot update the API endpoints.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about that, I haven't run into that situation, hopefully someone else will be able to answer. Good luck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A server that returns response code `200` or `201` with an **empty** response body and `Content-Type` specified as `application/json` is misconfigured, since an empty string is not valid JSON.

As the OP indicated, specifying `responseType: "text"` fixes the error, since the empty body is not parsed as JSON.

A workaround is to proceed with `responseType: "text"` and check if the response body is empty. If the response body is not empty, then call `JSON.parse(response)`.

### Example

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


type HttpOptions = {
  headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; };
  observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; };
  reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json" /* or "text" as "json" */;
  withCredentials?: boolean;
}

let get_http_options_text = (): HttpOptions => {
  return {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
    observe: "body",
    responseType: "text" as "json",  // @see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586
    withCredentials: true
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class MyHttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public post_body_as_string(url: string, body: any, http_params: HttpParams = null):
    Observable<any> {

    let options = get_http_options_text();
    if (http_params != null) {
      options['params'] = http_params;
    }

    return this.http.post<string>(url, body, options).pipe(
      map(response => {
        if (response !== '') {
          return JSON.parse(response);
        } else {
          return {}
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very well, I was hoping for a solution that uses just config options, but I guess in this case we can't avoid writing custom code to handle that.